# How do I create a new, uh, thing in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I think the vagueness of the question is part of the problem, so my real first question is, what do you call, in Angular, the *thing*.

The thing I'm trying to name is the view plus the controller, over the model of a single object.  I don't even know what to call it.  For things I know ahead of time I'm going to need, I've been creating *directives*, but what do you call one instance of the thing that a directive creates?

I have several situations where all of a sudden (in response to some external event), I have a new object in the model and I want to show it on the screen.  Angular seems to want me to list all the possible views *ab initio* in their parent view, but that isn't really reasonable in my case.  How, for example, would I list all the pop-ups and tool-tips and other stuff.

I'm down in some little edge case, deep in the controller code, and it needs to add something to the current view.  What's the accepted practice.

Incidentally, the $route/ng-view is one case of exactly this.  The view containing the ng-view, and the ng-view DIV itself, have no idea what the $route module is going to put in the ng-view.  I need the more general case of this strategy.

**EDIT**

People keep asking for an example.  How about this:  I'm making an equipment-requisition app.  When a user asks that one of the 1000 different type of equipment be sent to him, I need to display a pop-up that gathers addition information specific to that type.  If he asks for a screwdriver, the pop-up will ask about blade size, neck length, and handle composition; if he asks for an airplane, it will be a wizard ask him about engine size, fuel tanks, seating arrangement.  All the app knows on start-up is the list of all equipment types, and the name of the UI element that gathers all subsequent information about each particular type.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking for... You can see pop ups on the web site http://angularjs.org/ (check out code of any example, all the highlighted code has pop ups with explanation)

Comment: Obviously, if I could have made my question clearer, I would have.  Can you say it became unclear for you?  I was unable to find any example of code with pop-ups on angularjs.org; do you have a URL?

Comment: Simple tooltip http://jsfiddle.net/gxw5j/

Comment: @Vojta -- thanks, that's exactly, exactly wrong.  All the elements in your example *existed in the view*.  I need the control to realize that it needs a new element and create one.

Comment: A concrete example would go a long way in helping people understand your issue

Comment: @Malvolio well if Vojta's example is wrong and you want the control to realize that it needs a new element and create one that is just as bad as having it in the view. It's considered bad practice in Angular to have DOM manipulation occurring in your controller. I still don't really understand what you are trying to do here, but if you want to add logic to an element that reacts and injects new markup this is where you would use a directive. Essentially whether through an element, attribute or class you could make your markup inherently behave the way you want and act accordingly.

Comment: Down voted because there is obviously too much ambiguity in your statement.  Reduce the problem to its core, and you will get the help you are asking for.

Comment: A "thing" can be any*thing*; try to be more specific on your title.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm down in some little edge case, deep in the controller code, and it needs to add something to the current view. What's the accepted practice.

Somewhere, you need to define all of the views you'll need -- e.g., all of the equipment popups.  You could put each view into a separate file and use ng-include to dynamically pull in the one you currently need to display.  Define a property on your $scope (e.g., $scope.equipmentTypeViewUrl), then

```
<div ng-include src="equipmentTypeViewUrl"></div>
```

Since ng-view can only appear once per page, ng-include is probably not what you need to use if you need multiple levels of routing.

See also

- [create a single html view for multiple partial views in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577378/create-a-single-html-view-for-multiple-partial-views-in-angularjs)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/xIIyGpW8KUk/discussion
- [App design using Angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793609/app-design-using-angular-js)
- [Client Side Template with view per role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996018/client-side-template-with-view-per-role/13005658#13005658)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you think that you need to create the "thing" in controller, but actually you don't. The way two-way data binding works is that you change some attribute value, and the view changes based on that. I've never seen a use case where that's not enough, pop-ups and tooltips notwithstanding.

However, if you really must have the controller show something, you could utilize angular's events to do that. You would need two parts: a directive responsible for showing stuff (modifying DOM), and the controller. The controller would $broadcast an event with some parameters, and the directive would listen to those events using $on and react accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I do.  Otherwise, the view would have to have a comprehensive list of all the possible things it might display -- I cannot do ordinary OO things like inheritance.  If you don't believe me, look at $route/ng-view and ask yourself why *ng-view* doesn't know all the things that route might do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make sure I had some useful code coming in as the model...

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="attribute in attributes">
    <div class="widget" ng-repeat="input in attribute.inputs">
        <input type="{{input.type}}" ng-model="input.value" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm extremely limited in my knowledge, but all I know is if you have a definite structure to your model you can build a view that reacts to it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If all of those things are related to your original object (properties or in some way other) you could loop through the data, display the properties and if need use the keys and filters for a label. Imho it's not really an angular question, more one if your data structure. If you have a good data structure you could use a service for creating a related data-object.

For a related popup, you can use a directive and even process the model data there (only recommended if it has a consistent structure).

If you dislike this approach, you can process the data directly in the template.

But without more specific details, there will be no definite answer.