# create a single html view for multiple partial views in angularjs

Tags: routes, angularjs

I wish to create a single html file with multiple  tags. These  should act as separate individual views that are usually kept in partials folder. 
And then i wish to specify them in routing controller.
For now i am doing as follows:
app.js

```
    angular.module('productapp', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/productapp', {templateUrl: 'partials/productList.html', controller: productsCtrl}).
        when('/productapp/:productId', {templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html', controller: editCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/productapp'});
        }], 
        ['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode = true;
}]);
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "productapp">
<head>
<title>Search form with AngualrJS</title>
        <script src="../angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/products.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

in partials folder:
i have 2 html views named edit.html and productlist.html

instead of creating these 2 files i wish combine them into one in separate  and call them (the divs) through routing.
How do i do this?

Comment: Please explain. Do you want to add divs to index.html?

Comment: no not in index.html but in some other html file

Comment: why not use jquery? or just javascript to show/hide divs, all in the same div.

Answer (score 42):

You could use ng-switch to conditionally render your productList with an include, depending on the route parameters.

Try this in your config:

```
    angular.module('productapp', [])
      .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/productapp', {templateUrl: 'partials/productList.html', controller: productsCtrl})
        .when('/productapp/:productId', {templateUrl: 'partials/productList.html', controller: productsCtrl})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/productapp'});
```

And in your controller:

```
    function productsCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
      $scope.productId = $routeParams.productId;
    }
```

And in your html:

```
    <...productListHtml...>
    <div ng-switch="productId != null">
      <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-include="'partials/product.html'">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with nesting views and deep linking in Angular as $routerProvide doesn't support multiple ng-view.. But I found a possible solution how to make this happen [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-Nested-Views-Routing-And-Deep-Linking-With-AngularJS.htm). Its based on handing routes manually using request context and render context.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem, now there is a solution for it using: 
[UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#get-started)

The advantage of using this and not the ngRoute is that you can have multiple views in the same page using "ui-view" naming convention.