# AngularJS - basic App example not working, and how to debug Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm following an example where I can make the first part example work, but then making a small change to restructure it by adding a application doesn't work (but should do the same thing) -- very basic example.  Can you please help me understand

1) what's wrong with the code, and

2) how to debug this kind of thing

I'm including angular.min.js version 1.2.6

### Example that works

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="nameText" /> <span style="font-weight:bold"> {{ nameText }}</span>
        <h3>Listing1</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: nameText | orderBy: 'city' ">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city }} </li>
            </ul>
    </div>

   <script>
       function SimpleController($scope) {
           $scope.customers = [
               { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix'},
               { name: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Atlanta'},
               { name: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler'},
               { name: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle'}
           ];
       }
    </script>
    <script src="libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Similar Example that Doesn't Work

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
<head ng-app="demoApp">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="nameText" /> <span style="font-weight:bold"> {{ nameText }}</span>
        <h3>Listing1</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: nameText | orderBy: 'city' ">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city }} </li>
            </ul>
    </div>

   <script>
       var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

       function SimpleController($scope) {
           $scope.customers = [
               { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix'},
               { name: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Atlanta'},
               { name: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler'},
               { name: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle'}
           ];
       }

       demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);

    </script>
    <script src="libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you post some console messages?

Comment: It just looks like AngularJS isn't activated on anything.  Still need me to post a picture?  Not sure what you mean by console messages.

Comment: By 'console', I mean Web Inspector's or Firebug console tab, which containes application output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include angular script tag before tag with your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
<head ng-app="demoApp">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="nameText" /> <span style="font-weight:bold"> {{ nameText }}</span>
        <h3>Listing1</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: nameText | orderBy: 'city' ">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city }} </li>
            </ul>
    </div>

   <script src="libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

       function SimpleController($scope) {
           $scope.customers = [
               { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix'},
               { name: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Atlanta'},
               { name: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler'},
               { name: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle'}
           ];
       }

       demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);

    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The thing is, that in this expression:

```
    <script src="libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
```

`angular` is undefined

Also, here is [tutorial for debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging?hl=ru) in Google Chrome.

Comment: So the example and many sites say add the JS code includes at the bottom.  Is this not true with AngularJS?   Any references to AngularJS on where they say to do the includes?

Comment: @Ray I meant, that script tag, that includes angular from libraries dir should be before the code, that uses angular

Comment: But wait a minute -- not putting it at the top should only affect the "flash of uncompiled content", not affect the operation after the page is loaded, right?

Comment: Here is a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538125/angularjs-in-head-vs-body

Comment: @Ray Wait. I am not advicing you to put your scripts to the head tag! No way! It is good, that they are in body. The only thing you need is to swap them.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Regarding the debugging, how is it that I could know with the debugger why this did not work.  Thanks for your help.