# How do we load AngularJS at the end of body instead of the header?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

By default, AngularJS doesn't seem to work unless I put it in the `<head>`. Is there a way to put it at the end of the `<body>` instead?

My code looks like this in the footer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);

    myApp.controller("AppController",["$scope", "$http", function() {
        // so stuff with the $scope.
    }]);
});
```

EDIT 3/31/14:
Based on ederollora's answer and doing some research, I discovered that the call to `angular.bootstrap()` needs to be called *after* everything is defined. The above code becomes this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller("AppController",["$scope", "$http", function() {
        // so stuff with the $scope.
    }]);

    myApp.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]); // compile the app last
});
```

Also, in the interest of migrating my app from jQuery to Angular, I change the document.ready calls to the angular version:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller("AppController",["$scope", "$http", function() {
        // so stuff with the $scope.
    }]);

    myApp.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]); // compile the app last
});
```

It wasn't clear in the documentation that `angular.boostrap()` had to be called after defining everything, so I went and improved the documentation.

Comment: *"By default, AngularJS doesn't seem to work unless I put it in the `<head>`"* What do you mean? The `script` tag? That works fine in the `body`. Example: http://jsbin.com/zoyedeba/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/zoyedeba/1/edit).

Comment: [AngularJS does not need to be placed in the HEAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538125/angularjs-in-head-vs-body)...

Comment: Hmmm.... I need to find out why it doesn't work at the end of `<body>` for me then.

Comment: The problem all along was that I was calling `angular.bootstrap()` in the footer before defining my controllers and directives, which doesn't work. `bootstrap()` has to be called after everything is defined. This piece of information was missing from the AngularJS documentation for `bootstrap`, and I got it added in this pull request: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/6921

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From AngularJS doc page:

> Angular  Tag
>
> This example shows the recommended path for integrating Angular with what we call automatic initialization.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app>
  <body>
  ...
  <script src="angular.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

> 1. Place the script tag at the bottom of the page. Placing script tags at the end of the page improves app load time because the HTML loading is not blocked by loading of the angular.js script. You can get the latest bits from http://code.angularjs.org. Please don't link your production code to this URL, as it will expose a security hole on your site. For experimental development linking to our site is fine.

The information was found: [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#angular-script-tag)

Comment: Thanks! I'll post back when I find out why it doesn't work at the end of `<body>` for me.

Comment: yes please, and I'll edit my answer so that it better fits your question.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: In this link you have information about Manual Initialization: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization . Before manual initialization, there's some info about Automatic Initialization. Reading both topics should give you some advice

Comment: aaaah. I found the problem. It works fine in the footer, as long as it is not inside `$(document).ready(function() {});`. Any idea why it won't work inside jQuery's document.ready function?

Comment: Oooh. Do I need to do that same initialization in document.ready?

Comment: As far as I know initilization, should not be placed in javascript. You should follow either the example I wrote you in my answer of the link about Manual Initilization

Comment: No you don't need. In case you want to control EXACTLY when it is initialized then yes, you should add some javascript code. BUT if automatic initilization is OK for you then use Auto Initialization. It initializes as soon as DOM loads (DOM load event called DOMContentLoaded) or script tag is found. So placing the script tag `<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular.js"></script>` right before `</body>` should be OK

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm fine with automatic initialization, however trying the manual initialization isn't working. I'm trying this: http://hastebin.com/qahuqikogi.xml

Comment: have you tried exactly the code that manual initilization states in the docs?

Comment: I saw the link, first `/path/to/angular.js` is just an example, or the actual code?

Comment: That's just an example... but you can assume it is the actual angular.js library. Everything works fine when I let it be automatic, but if I wrap it in `angular.element(document).ready(function() {...});` and add the `angular.bootstrap()` line it won't work. I'm doing exactly as the demo. Here's my code verbatim. This works: http://hastebin.com/disecikegi.xml And this doesn't: http://hastebin.com/xugavupubo.xml

Comment: I can't get manual initialization to work for the life of me. Here's my *entire* code: http://hastebin.com/xoxoniyaja.xml Here's the AngularJS error it's giving me: http://bit.ly/1dIuMY1 Seems like I did it like in the manual initialization doc, but of course I have way more code.

Comment: Well I'm definetely not an experto on the field but could you pastebin (or any other) the exception trace you personally suffer from?

Comment: However if you still got problems with manual init, I shouldn't worry too much since angularJS is enough intelligent to load the script as soon as the DOM is loaded or the script tag is reached. Then it could be more optimized than manual.

Comment: I figured it out! I had to move the call to `angular.bootstrap()` to a position *after* setting up my controller ("RootController" in my case). So I guess `angular.bootstrap` compiles the app, which relies on having modules, directives, etc, all already configured before compilation happens.

Comment: Good, please if you can edit my answer so that it becomes more complete adding your exact problems solution. We could help more people!

Comment: So, "the recommended way" is not even used in the "get started" example? https://code.angularjs.org/0.10.6/docs-0.10.6/misc/started

Comment: Developers guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#angular-script-tag. Maybe getting started means just that.