# What problems I will face if I put angular.js at the bottom of the body?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, performance, nonblocking

On [anguler official guide - bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) I read:

> Place the script tag at the bottom of the page. Placing script tags at
>   the end of the page improves app load time because the HTML loading is
>   not blocked by loading of the angular.js script. You can get the
>   latest bits from http://code.angularjs.org. Please don't link your
>   production code to this URL, as it will expose a security hole on your
>   site. For experimental development linking to our site is fine.

And also on the same site [AngularJS ngCloack](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) I read:

> For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head
>   section of the html document

I am a neophyte in angularjs, and my question is:

**what problems I might encounter if you put the angulas.js script at the bottom of the body**, so as to make my html non-blocking? And where I can learn how to deal with this ploblem? Thanks you all!

Comment: Duplicate: [AngularJS in HEAD vs BODY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538125/angularjs-in-head-vs-body)

Comment: I now that angular.js is very lightweight, but this problem (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) it's a real problem and I would put all the script at the bottom of the body And I heard that there could be problems with angular.js. But the response on stackoverflow are not exhaustive, I asked if anyone knows something from which I can learn (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Duplicate? I ask what ploblem I could face and where I learn why this happens and how I can resolve...

Comment: When you load AngularJS at the bottom of the page you will face "flash of uncompiled content"

Comment: I never have problems loading angular at bottom. Use `ng-cloak` for sections that require interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that if you load the script at the bottom, then for `ng-cloak` to work properly, the CSS for the `ng-cloak` classes need to be loaded at the top.

From the Docs:

> `ngCloak` works in cooperation with the following css rule embedded within `angular.js` and `angular.min.js`
>
> ```
> [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
>   display: none !important;
> }
> ```
>
> For the best result, the `angular.js` script must be loaded in the head section of the html document; alternatively, the css rule above must be included in the external stylesheet of the application.

-- [AngularJS ng-cloak Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Ah, thanks you. I thought it was a general problem, however, it was limited to that function. thanks for the clarity