# Avoiding expressions being shown on page load

Tags: angularjs

In an AngularJS video at one point I saw how to avoid an expression being visible before the Javascript parses it.  But I can't remember how it was done...

I have a `<div id='message'>{{$root.initializing.status}}</div>` that I'd like to say "Loading..." before AngularJS has a chance to parse it.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As the others mentioned, use ng-cloak but also add the following to your CSS if it is the first to load in your page.

```
[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],.ng-cloak{display:none !important}
```

This will ensure that your div template is hidden.  Below that div template, add something like

Loading...

The assignment of the $root.initializing.status with cause a true value for ng-hide.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSwFd/) and the following is the code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
    <div id='message'>{{$root.initializing.status}}</div>
    <div ng-hide="$root.initializing.status">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($timeout, $scope) {
///simulating loading
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.$root = {
            initializing: {
                status: 'Complete!'
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Use ng-cloak http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

or ng-bind http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBind

```
Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span>!
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14076004/1172872

Comment: But which one is better?

Comment: @pkk: For show and hide necessity, ngCloak. In case of using element as placeholder, go for ng-bind

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id='message'><span ng-bind="$root.initializing.status"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide an expression with ngCloak, see this answer:

[Prevent double curly brace notation from displaying momentarily before angular.js compiles/interpolates document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j)

As for showing loading, you can just set $root.initializing.status to a default value of "Loading" and then reset it when you get your data.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I'm still seeing `{{myvar}}` flash on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-cloak` directive to avoid the flicker on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds this information useful, I'm using the following workaroud.

```
<div ng-class="{'hide', '': ctrl.pageLoaded}">...</div>
```

and

```
.hide{display: none;}
```

I use this to hide all content that as angular expressions until the controller is loaded, where I set `this.pageLoaded = true`.