# Is there a way to avoid AngularJS show all hidden elements until the page loads?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All elements with the `ng-hide` attribute are visible until the page loads (and angular hide them) – it makes a strange web page appearance until that. With jquery, I was used to set `style="display:none"` and show them when the js is done.

Am I doing something wrong in **AngularJS**? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Example of the page showing all hidden elements while loading:
[image]

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this looks like it may do what you want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091364/avoiding-expressions-being-shown-on-page-load.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Thanks for all perfect answers.

The `ng-cloak` does the trick:

- Documentation: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)
- Step-by-step how to set it up: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091364/avoiding-expressions-being-shown-on-page-load)

Remembering that recomendation:

> The directive can be applied to the  element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

Answer (score 9):

Just Try

```
<div ng-app ng-cloak>
//Code 
</div>
```

Docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: this answer should have been marked as comment based on time stamp. :)

Comment: @deathrace thanks for your kind concern. I will take care of that in future

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `ng-cloak`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

It will prevent this flicker.

Answer (score 2):

check this official doc 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak
add this directive to your body tag with custom css included at beginning or in html directly