# view loading time display in output angular variable name with {{ }} in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular variable name is display in output when the view is loading.

`test_1.js` Controller file has assign variable

```
$scope.title = "My View";
```

`test_1.html` is html view file.

```
<h1> {{ title }} </h1>
```

**Output :-**

```
My View
```

But some little time display

```
{{ title }}
```

when the process is completed then display right value of `title` variable.

I want this `{{ title }}` type of output is not display in browser.

How it is possible ?

Comment: what you are seeing is the raw HTML before Anguar gets in the picture and bind everything, and update the variables. A possible approach would be to hide the whole HTML via inline CSS and then programatically show it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091364/avoiding-expressions-being-shown-on-page-load possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**ngCloak**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak) to avoid this problem

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.
>
> The directive can be applied to the `<body>` element, but typically a
>   fine-grained application is prefered in order to benefit from
>   progressive rendering of the browser view.

Example

```
<h1 ng-cloak> {{ title }} </h1>
```