# How to remove delay from ngShow initialization? When ng-cloak fails?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I've run into the exact [same problem found in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146096/ngshow-load-delay-issue). However both answers did not work in my case.

Video of my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByjmwmamemM

[image]

When my app loads, there are several popovers with ng-show checks on all of them. They all start out `false` however for 3-4 secs (long time) the popovers show up, then disappear.

According to the answer in the question I linked to above I should try to load Angular at the top in the head section, and if that doesn't work then add `.ng-cloak` to my CSS and to the `divs` in question.

Both did not work :(

Anyone else run into this problem before?

**Index.html:**

[image]

```
<body ng-app="tickertags">

    <div ui-view></div>
```

**dashboard.html** <- first template loaded into `ui-view`

```
<div ng-controller="DashCtrl">
    <top-notification></top-notification>
    <alerts-panel></alerts-panel>
    <search-popover></search-popover>
    <tags-search></tags-search>
    <tags-filter></tags-filter>

    <div class="dash-body" ng-click="bodyClick()">
        <header>
            <platform-header></platform-header>
            <control-header></control-header>
            <view-header></view-header>
        </header>

        <tickers-panel></tickers-panel>
        <tags-panel></tags-panel>

        <section id="panel-activity" class="activity-panel">
            <chart-header></chart-header>
            <chart-iq></chart-iq>
            <social-media-panel></social-media-panel>
        </section>
    </div>

    <overlay></overlay>
</div>
```

---

**The popovers:**

[image]

**searchPopover:** (3-4 secs before hiding)

```
<div ng-show="searchPopoverDisplay" class="search-popover" ng-cloak>
```

**tagSearchPopover:** (3-4 secs before hiding)

```
<div ng-show="tagsSearch.tagsFuzzyResults" class="tag-search-popover" ng-cloak>
```

**tagFilterPopover:** (<- this popover disappears the fastest, .5 sec)

```
<div ng-show="tagsFilterOn" class="tags-filter-popover" ng-click="captureClick()" ng-cloak>
```

**ng-cloak**

```
// ng-cloak
[ng\:cloak],
[ng-cloak],
[data-ng-cloak],
[x-ng-cloak],
.ng-cloak,
.x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hide them by default in css, then override when angular loads. The 3-4 second delay could be the time it's taking to fetch and load angular amidst all the other requests you're making (you should check your network panel).

Comment: Thanks yeah I was thinking that may be the way to go... using a toggle on `ng-class` instead.

Comment: Do you want to post the answer? This worked :) used `ng-class` : `.display-on {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}`

Comment: Done, glad that worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide them by default in css, then override when angular loads. The 3-4 second delay could be the time it's taking to fetch and load angular amidst all the other requests you're making (you should check your network panel).

```
.display-on {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

---

```
ng-class="{'display-on': searchPopoverDisplay}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but I have another solution.

Using the bootstrap.css:

```
<div class="collapse" ng-class="{'collapse': [falsy after ng evaluates] }"
```

This will remove the collapse class if required, but it will start off as hidden until angular can evaluate it.

Otherwise use any class that sets display:none, and remove it with ng-class.

Answer (score 1):

To make a `div` hidden by default and prevent it from being shown before the page is completely loaded, you can add `ng-hide` to `class` attribute. E.g.:

```
<div ng-show="searchPopoverDisplay ng-hide" class="search-popover" ng-cloak>
```

Comment: this is the simplest and most efficient solution, it forces ng-hide until ng-show (eventually) evals to true