# what is : and \ in css square brackets?

Tags: css, angularjs

I was reading this answer [Alternative to ng-show/-hide or how to load only relevant section of DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068711/alternative-to-ng-show-hide-or-how-to-load-only-relevant-section-of-dom) and am not sure what the  `\:` 
in `[ng\:cloak]` mean. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: That should just be a character escape. `[ng\:cloak]` selector should mean any tag with the `ng:cloak` attribute. [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/bhtqcpqr/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You escape special characters in css by a backslash. The one you've used targets.

```
<anyelement ng:clock="somevalue">
```