# Many instances of ngIf vs ngShow for complex UI and forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found a few questions regarding `ngShow` vs `ngIf` but nothing that addressed my use case all that well.

- [Alternative to ng-show/-hide or how to load only relevant section of DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068711/alternative-to-ng-show-hide-or-how-to-load-only-relevant-section-of-dom)
- [what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)
- [When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

I understand the differences between the two directives but for an application with many conditional UI elements (content, toolbar buttons, dropdowns, form fields, etc - some of which are in `ngRepeats`) which is the better choice - `ngShow` or `ngIf`? As the user navigates the application and loads different content into the UI, these conditions will be evaluated so this will happen regularly as opposed to one time as it might with something like user preferences or permissions. Also, much of the content that is conditionally displayed contains `{{bindings}}`.  The number of extra watches is my concern with `ngShow` while the large number of DOM manipulations concerns me with `ngIf`.

Is there a best practice or guidance for this type of situation?  Is there some threshold where one makes sense over the other? Or is it simply a matter of trying both to determine the performance impacts of each (easier said than done)?

Comment: I don't think there's a right answer here and you're definitely on the right track. Yes I'd limit the logic within the ng-repeats, however new with Angular 1.3 if you're on it has one way binding which will help.

Answer (score 0):

Always use ng-if if possible. Content which is not in the DOM must not be watched etc. if you have bindings. Therefore it performs better. 
Use ng-show only if

1. you have complicated event handlers on DOM elements which can be hidden
2. the hide/show value changes extremely often (DOM manipulation is expensive)