# Angular. Text rendered by angular is blinking when page loads

Tags: angularjs

I have simple test page

```
<head>
     ........
     <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     .......
     <label>Name:</label>
     <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name">
     <h1>Welcome {{name}}!</h1>
</body>
```

When page loads first time I see {{name}} on page

[image]

After a half of a second it disappears

[image]

that makes quite annoying effect of blinking. What am I missing and how can I avoid it?

Comment: You could vanish this behavior via using `ngClock` directive or `ng-bind` directive, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14076004/2435473)

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times on this site.  Search for ngCloak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**ngCloak**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to prevent this behavior.