# angularjs: how to change a template for a specific ng-view or ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

I have few ng-views and ng-includes in one single page,

I would like to change the template of a specific ng-include upon route change?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to use the same template, but within that template, use ng-switch in combination with ng-include to load the appropriate template.  Your controller can set some $scope property that ng-switch will use to determine which template to load.

Andy already provided an exmple of such here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12584774/215945