# App design using Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

Been working on building a huge app using angular js. Have seen too many questions on the same topic on how best we can design an app, but still am lil confused.

A basic app usually has a

> 1) Login page/Index page
>
> 2) Home page - with headers and footers. Body being the `partial/composite` which keeps on changing.

since we don't have handle to load multiple ng-views, which is best way to structure the **Home** page such a way that we have one single **HomePage** container with headers and footers and Body is loaded dynamically via `$route`.

Right now I have designed it using a single **LoginContainerPage** which loads **Login** page and home pages via $routers, but since only a single ng-view is allowed i cant use another `ng-view` within the **Home** page to laod the body dynamically again. i am not keen to use `ng-include` as well.

Another way to go is keep **LoginPage** outside the `$route` and start routing from **HomePage** such that the Body is loaded dynamically.

Wanted to check if there are any better ideas around.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have a look at my pull request about multiple named ng-views https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1198

Comment: I think you've examined and understood the alternatives pretty well.  At this point, I'd go with "start routing from HomePage". FYI, here's Andy's ng-switch + ng-include idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577378/create-a-single-html-view-for-multiple-partial-views-in-angularjs

Comment: @mohangopi please take more time in your suggested edits.  Your formatting is superfluous and distracting.

Answer (score 2):

well in the project i'm working on with angularjs i took this approach:
i had a header that was the main navigation system i made a controller for that that handled the navigation system and knew about where i am right now. i had an ngView which loaded my main content based on routes but sometimes i needed different templates to be loaded and compiled base on some event for instance ajax loaded tabs. i implemented these types of things using ngInclude that the main controller on the view had the responsibility to choose the template and include it, i believe there is no need for multiple ngViews you can simply use scopes to implement different things and handle different parts of your app with different controllers and data. i guess the best idea for you is to make your login page separate.
i did this in my project. my login page was the only non-Ajax page that i had.

edit:
for authetication part if you wish to implement the authentication through angular you migh want to check [this](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth).