# Using angular $routeProvider without history and url changes

Tags: angularjs, browser-history, route-provider

I want to use $routeProvider for loading the partials from the server, but I don't want the url # value changes and the history changes ( App should go back to previous url without multiple back button clicks after multiple route changes within my app )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the # symbol from angular.js urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)

Comment: Its not. The one you have mentioned is for only url, to remove # from hashbang mode to have meaningful html5 url

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. As far as I know $routeProvider needs those Url changes.

Another way to do this would be to use ng-show and ng-hide to display partials on the page without changing the url. You can load the partials from the server using $http or $resource and if it needs it, use the $compile to execute any angular in those partials (ie directives).