# Remove the numeric symbol from your root url in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Angular js appends the extenssion "/#" to my url (eg. http://example.com/#/) but I'd like my root direction to be completely clean (without the /#).

Is there a way to override this to have a clean home url?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the # symbol from angular.js urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)

Answer (score 1):

Set `html5Mode` to `true` in your config via `$locationProvider`:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

See: [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `$location` provider in order to get rid of the hash `#` in the url.  [This documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location) goes through how to configure for html5 mode.

This SO Question will also help:
[Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. This could be achieved by

1. Add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) in the config

   ```
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
   ```
2. Add base url in the Index.html head tag

   ```
   <base href="/app/index.html">
   ```