# After removing the # from url, I lost direct access to my urls

Tags: angularjs

in order to make nice urls, I decide to remove the # from my ulrs using the tip from the following question [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls) Now, I realized that my urls are not working if I try a direct access to them. from the given example in the related question if put the url below directly in the browser `http://localhost/phones`

I'll get a 404.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You could have saved me a click by just saying that you enabled the html5 mode with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. And, to answer your question, you need to instruct your server to route all non-asset requests to index.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the # symbol from angular.js urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)

Comment: @Stewie, this looks like what I am missing 'instruct your server to route all non-asset requests to index.html', is it possible to do that on htaccess?

Comment: Yes, it certainly is.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write server side code that will generate the page that you were previously depending on the client-side JavaScript to generate.

This will then be the initial view for that URL.

If the client supports JavaScript (and the JavaScript doesn't fail for any reason) it will then take over for future interactions.

Otherwise, the regular links and forms you (should) have in the page will function as normal without JS.

Comment: there is no alternative? a redirect via htaccess is not suitable?

Comment: Redirect to where? The homepage? Then the homepage loads. That defeats the object.