# Cannot make route work for angularjs in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans-7, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to set up the most basic example of angularjs routing in a Netbeans 7.4 HTML5 project but I can't get any of the examples I have seen to work. This is the crucial part of the index.html file:

```
<a href="/mypartial">my partial</a>
<div ng-view></div>
```

...and for my app.js file:

```
$routeProvider.when("/mypartial", {templateUrl: "/partials/mypartial.html"});
```

The website is hosted at `localhost:8383` with the Netbeans embedded lightweight server which means that the website will be accessible at `localhost:8383/[projecttitle]/index.html` where [projecttitle] is the name of the Netbeans HTML5 project. However when I click on the link to "my partial" I get redirected to `localhost:8383/mypartial` resulting in a http 404 error. I know that the routing works because if I change the path in .when from "/mypartial" to "/" it shows my partial HTML file right away.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the very same issue today. Try add the # symbol

```
    <a href="#/mypartial">my partial</a>
```

related post:
[Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)