# AngularJS unwanted Behavior when reloading page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I'm developing an Angular application with the MEAN stack, so suppose you got an express route that make a query to the databse, the results are sent in the response:

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res){
    Todo.find({}, "", function(err,todos){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(todos);
     }); 

});
```

In the client-side: 
 
**Controller :**

```
  ...
  Todo.get().success(function(data){  //i got the service with the $http call
      $scope.todos = data;
  });
```

When I go to localhost:8080/#/api, I can see my partial and the data I requested.
The problem that I'm having is that if I omit the hashtag, i don't see the partial, I only see the response data in JSON format. 
I also tried to use html5 mode, but if I reload I got the same behavior. 

*Any ideas on how can I avoid this behavior??*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the # symbol from angular.js urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything after the `#` isn't sent to the server. So when you go to `localhost:8080/#/api`, expressjs just sees a request to `/` and returns the AngularJS template. AngularJS then routes the browser page using the `/#/api`, which called the `Todo.get()` and (I assume) makes a call to `localhost:8080/api`, returning the data from the DB.

That's why you only get the data when you omit the hash and when you use html5 mode.

I would suggest changing your API call to:
`/api/todos` - return data from the db

And change your AngularJS route to just use:
`/todos` - show the partial and data requested

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, yes the Todo.get() make that call, I understand what you're suggesting, but if the user knows the API call `/api/todos ` , he will see the data anyway dosen't he?

Comment: Yes, but the user will be able to find the data either way if they inspect the requests in the browser console. You cannot hide an API url behind other URLs so that the user cannot find them, but you can make it so that user won't find the URL by accidentally removing the #

Comment: Thanks a lot, i get it, but now i thinking that if the user remove the #, he will get a Get error, but maybe i can catch that error in the routes handlers in the server, sending the index.html, and then angular will be catching that route.

Comment: In that case, you should catch localhost:8080/todos and redirect the user to localhost:8080/#/todos. Ideally, you would use HTML5 pushstate and not use the #