# Get resource parameters from url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs, Given a url `http://example.com/photos/123` and url template `http://example.com/photos/:id` (that is used in $resource). How to get the hash: {id: 123}?

Comment: Seems the logic needed is deep inside ngRoute implementation in switchRouteMatcher()/pathRegExp() but does not handle hostname:port parsings. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js

Answer (score 0):

You would use Angular [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams).

For example in your controller:

```
$routeParams.id
```

would return '123'

**Edit:** As pointed out by okigan the default routing assumes you have a location hash so your route would need to be http://example.com/#/photos/123. However you can turn this off to retain your desired routing by turning on html5mode. Please see [removing #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)

**Update:** You can also access the url parts using regular Javascript. The following would get the second url part.

```
id = (window.location.pathname).split('/')[2]
```

You could use this as a base to extend the functionality.

Comment: The url is not related to the current controller route ($routeParams will get params after # which is not in the above url. If not, please provide more complete example.

Comment: You don't have to use the # in html5 so it is still valid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls. Otherwise the Op can alter his routing to achieve the same thing.

Comment: OP question does not use uiRouter so there are no relevant $routeParams

Comment: I've updated my answer for using plain javascript to get the url part. There may be another Angular approach that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

All url parameters can be accessed with the $routeParams service:

From the [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24routeParams) documentation:

> The route parameters are a combination of $location's search() and path(). The path parameters are extracted when the $route path is matched.

Example:

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
//
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:1, sectionId:2, search:'moby'}
```

**EDIT: Given the below comments, I extend my answer**

```
// The example url you provided.
var url = 'http://example.com/photos/123';
// We get a list with all the parts of the url.
var partList = url.split(/\/|\?|&|=|\./g);
// We get the bit that we know is the photo's id.
var idPart = partList[5];
```

Comment: same as Asta's answer: The url is not related to the current controller route ($routeParams will get params after # which is not in the above url. If not, please provide more complete example.

Comment: I'm afraid that if it isn't registered and it isn't a query string you will have to parse for it manually. There is no standard for other parameter.

Comment: Let me see if I get you. You have a string and you want the 123 part because you know that's an ID?

Comment: Yes, a full url to a resource and I know the structure of the resource, so would like to get the parameters extracted. The logic is actually similar to ngRoute.switchRouteMatcher, but that's an internal function so not accessible and it mis-interprets hostname:99 as a parameter.

Comment: I think what you need is a good Regular Expression or a split that can handle that n-th part of your url. Would like like something like that in my answer?