# SPA & Spring - how to load AngularJS 'resources' that require route params without the .html postfix

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a single-page application (SPA) and want to serve up 'static' resources (HTML/JS files) from a Spring MVC stack but yet have the static HTML file treated like traditional Spring views and using the `ResourceHandler` so that the `/app.html` static resource doesn't get resolved to `http://example.com/app.html` (i.e. doesn't show the .html posfix in the URL) .

so Example: user goes to http://example.com/ABC123 - this then goes to a handler that does a redirect with the a route paramter for Angular to http://example.com/app.html#/ABC123 but it continues to appear as `http://example.com/ABC123`

Is that possible?

Comment: I believe you will find this useful (especially the section about the HTML5 mode): https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate parts to your question. One is how to get rid of the hash in the URI, and the other is how to suppress the `app.html` in the URI but still resolve to an actual `app.html` file that loads your Angular routes, controllers and such.

For the first concern, see [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls).

For the second, you can do this in your web MVC configuration. I lifted this technique right out of Spring's [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java):

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/app.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    }

    ... whatever other config you have ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Willie - that was one approach I had took but when the user clicks on 'http://example.com/#12345' the 12345 gets dropped (due to the forward) so when the app.html is loaded then it doesn't have the correct context to work with (in this case the 12345)..

Comment: Try example.com/#/12345. But I am actually using the technique that I describe above (though I keep the hashes) and it works just fine. Forwarding, unlike redirection, happens on the server side, so it shouldn't be dropping anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing all the routing on the server side I think the routing on the client side is no longer needed - the downside to this is that if the user moves through different records you will have to do a server side call for each record.

Another option would be to use http://example.com/ to serve the app and then your Angular app
would use  http://example.com/#/ABC123 not exactly what you wanted but close

Comment: The client-side routing complements the server-side routing. The client-side handles the UI and the server-side handles the API requests.