# why it's appending #/... in location.hash

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angular js for my app.

Here , My Angular code as :

```
var app = angular.module('TaskManager', ['ngCookies']);

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookieStore) {

  $scope.login = function(str) {
    console.log(".......... login called......");

       $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../TaskManager/public/user/login',
        data: $.param({
          email: email.value,
          password: password.value
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      })
        .success(function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        var result = data.response;
        console.log(result);

        if (result == "success") {          

          //storing value at cookieStore
          $cookieStore.put("loggedin", "true");
          $cookieStore.put("loggedUserId", data.user_id);
          $cookieStore.put("password", data.password);
          $cookieStore.put("type", data.type);
          $cookieStore.put("email", data.email);             

          location.href='Dashboard.html';                      

        } else alert(data.message);
      });         
});   


app.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookieStore) {    

  $scope.users = [];    

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '../TaskManager/public/task/tasklist',
    data: $.param({
      logged_userid: userId,
      password: password,
      status: 'All',
      user_id: useridToFetch
    }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  })
    .success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.users = data.users;

  });       

  //location.hash="";    
  console.log(window.location);
});
```

It works fine but when it redirects to the dashboard page after logged in, the `location.hash` is being assigned with the `#/PAGE_NAME`. it becomes `location.hash=#/PAGE_NAME`which results the URL value repetition.

Like:

```
http://localhost:8085/NovaTaskManager/Dashboard.html#/Dashboard.html
```

I tried to clear hash at DashboardController, Which clears for a while but as soon as the page is  refreshed the earlier URL appears again.

Don't know:

```
   1. why location.hash is getting assigned by default ?
   2. How it can be resolved ?
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls you have to set $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: I've made very basic plnkr http://run.plnkr.co/g6g6oZeK7zMoGEHJ/ when you click on hello it redirects to 'test.html', code here http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f?p=preview dunno why it happens for you. Do you include ngRoute

Comment: @ Kishore... thank you. It's worked for me. would you please post it as an answer so that I can accept the most quickest answer... once again... thank you.