# Is there a Grunt plugin to compile angular ng-views for server side rendering?

Tags: gruntjs, server-side, ng-view

I have a simple `angular` app managed by `Grunt.js`. I use the angular router for different pages:

#### index.html

```
...
<body ng-app="app">
   ...
   <div ng-view></div>
   ...
</div>
...
```

#### _users.html

```
<h1>Users</h1>
...
```

#### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/_home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/users', {
            templateUrl: 'views/_users.html',
            controller: 'UsersCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);

// ... controllers
```

The routing works fine for client side rendering, e.g requests of the form `site.com`, `site.com/#/users`, etc. If I apply `$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true })`, a direct call for `site.com/users` will fail, because there are no `users.html` or `users/index.html` files. Is there a smart grunt plugin which knows to render the views inside the layout when building a distribution directory? That is, generate a directory structure like for every nested view:

```
dist
├── index.html
└── users
│   └── index.html
├── css
│   └── app.css
└── js
    └── app.js
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why server side rendering ? You just want to have regular URLs with Angular ? Then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Comment: Yeah, and it works fine while navigating inside the app. But say you paste the link `site.com/users` in the browser - assuming a completely static server - you'll get a 404. You need to kickstart the clientside app somehow, and without a static html with some angular code in it, this doesn't happen. No?

Comment: So, at the moment, when you copy/paste site.com/#/users in your browser, you get a 404 ?

Comment: Nope, that one works as expected. But using it without the hash doesn't.

Comment: Ok I finally get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So, to sum up our discussion in comments :**

1. To get nice urls : you should configure `$locationProvider` and set `html5Mode` to **true**
2. Then, your server should look at the requested folders (i.e. looking into the folder my-folder for the URL site.com/my-folder/) so it won't work
3. So you have to make a basic rewrite rule in your htaccess (assuming you're working on Apache server), something like that (assuming index.html is the entry point of your app :

>

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
```

*From Angular doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side*

Unless if you really want to have static files to serve to the client (for any reason), this is the solution.