# Zurb Foundation Off Canvas sub-menu not working with Angular

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I have the following copied from Foundation to get an Off Canvas sub-menu working:

```
<li class="has-submenu">
   <a href="#">Foo</a>
   <ul class="left-submenu">
      <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
      <li><label>Level 1</label></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

When I click on 'Foo', the submenu does not come up, I go to my home page.
I believe because the link is `#`, and that's what Angular uses.
Is there a way to change Foundation's use of `#` in this case to get the submenu to work?

Answer (score 1):

> I believe because the link is `#`, and that's what Angular uses.

Yes, you are right. The first possibility to solve this is to [turn on html5mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14771091/3780766) but it is not always possible (e.g. because of setup of your server).

Another solution is to keep `href` blank - if you don't need hash tags for anchors but only to open the sub-menu, the functionality is much the same:

```
<li class="has-submenu">
   <a href="">Foo</a>
   <ul class="left-submenu">
      <li class="back"><a href="">Back</a></li>
      <li><label>Level 1</label></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, did you figure out what was wrong ?
I tried turning html5 mode on, or having empty href but it is not working for me