# Without giving # in url I'll get a 404 error

Tags: angularjs, html, url, url-routing, angularjs-routing

Is it possible to not to give # symbol from url to display record by giving id from url directly?
I am developing a website in which I have only one view page as `Login.html`.
I need to access it by giving id of user from url as `abc.in/1` here 1 is id of user. I set Login.html as a default page and when I try to access it by giving `abc.in/1` ,i.e. id in url it can not display the record. but when I give `abc.in#/1` it displays the record properly. I dont want to access it by giving `#` in url.
My code is as follow-

```
    <html ng-app="myApp" style="height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <base href="/">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title style="color: white;">c60</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <script src="../app/js/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    ---record details
    </body>
</html>
```

and in app.js-

```
    angular.module('myApp', [
      'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies',
      'myApp.filters',
      'myApp.services',
      'myApp.directives',
      'myApp.controllers',
      'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ngDragDrop'  //'ngSanitize',
    ]).
    config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

           $routeProvider.when('/:id',
          {
              templateUrl: '/Login.html',
              controller: 'LoginController'
          });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '' });

        //check browser support
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });                    
        }
    }])
```

How to do that? I just dont want to give # in url to display a record of perticular id provided in url.I need a clean url.How to do that?

I tried to remove the # from my ulrs using the tip from the following question [Removing the # symbol from angular.js urls](http://Removing%20the%20#%20symbol%20from%20angular.js%20urls) .Now, the issue is that my url is not working if I try a direct access to them. from the given example in the related question if put the url below directly in the browser http://localhost/phones ; in my case it is `abc.in/1`

I'll get a 404 error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to suppress the # in the url of an angular application. To do so, you need to configure the $locationProvider which you already have injected in your app config. Add the following after the $routeProvider configuration

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Finally add the following to the head section of your html file

```
<base href="/">
```

A couple of things seem to be wrong here. First even when you are having only one view in your app, it is nice to have something like an index.html which will host your ng-view directive. then when you navigate to the one view of your app, that view will be loaded where you have the ng-view directive. Secondly, from your app.js, you have something as shown below

```
$routeProvider.when('/:id',
      {
          templateUrl: '/Login.html',
          controller: 'LoginController'
      });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '' });
```

So this clearly says that when you enter '/' or '/1' for example in the address bar of your browser  your application will fetch login.html as stated in the templateUrl. However, in your test you are entering abc.in/1 (which I do not know where it comes from)in the url address bar of your browser. when this url is checked in the route provider's routes, no match will be found. Hence you you get a 404 error. To make the matter worse your $routeProvider.otherwise is redirecting to empty string. The right thing to do is state the various routes with their respective templateUrl  for your application and set otherwsise to redirect to the root of your application which in your case is still login.html or index.html if you add that now as you have only one view. Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited my question. I give     `<base href="/">` after head tag in  Logi.html page and I already injected `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in app.js..But it still gives an error as

`HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.`. When I entered `abc.in/1` (i.e. id of record) it gives this error.

Comment: This solution can only replaces `#` from url with `/` . I dont want to give `#` in url. I want plain url as `abc.in/1`. As per your solution, when I give `abc.in#1` it converts this url as `abc.in/1` and displays result of record. But all I want is that no `#` in url. I need to give only `abc.in/1` and by using this url I need to display record.

Comment: Can you post your latest app.js for us to review?

Comment: I updated the question. but the problem remains same. This solution can only replaces # from url with / . I dont want to give # initially in url. I want plain url as abc.in/1. As per your solution, when I give abc.in#1 it converts this url as abc.in/1 and displays result of record. but I dont want to "REPLACE" # with / but I want to give / in url

Comment: @SayliVaidya Were you able to resolve this without "replacing" # with / ?