# How can I hide the hash route in Angularjs

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs

I would like to keep the integrity of the hash like for breadcrumbs and such but i just don't want to display the hash in the route. Is there any way to keep the hash in the background but hide it in the URL? I have done some research on this already and I have found some answers that all get rid of the hash completely. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to configure $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14771362/3687474

Comment: can't have it both ways. If not using html5 mode and there is no hash, routers aren't set to determine path.

Comment: @aorfevre Thank you, but would this take away the SPA piece of it?

Comment: @RitesBless not at all, you just need to set up server to map server paths  to app entry point and follow the SEO and `<base>` guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('scotchy', [])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller : mainController
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Read this blog, it should have every thing you need to know. [Pretty URLs](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)