# Angularjs ngRoute # in URL

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

This is my angularjs routing

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
  }
});
```

This link works as expected

```
<a href="/home">Home</a>
```

However, when I type `http://localhost:3000/home` directly in the address bar, I get a blank page. Any idea why this is happening?

Typing `http://localhost:3000/#/home` redirects to `http://localhost:3000/home` and works as expected.

Comment: html5Mode requires your server to be configured to do URL rewriting.  It doesn't matter which router you are using.  There is a good article on the FAQs for UI-Router that explains possible configurations depending on your server: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: also, you honestly don't need to check `window.history && window.history.pushState`,  `html5Mode` will automatically fall back if those features aren't available.

Comment: I guess that answers the question. Thanks!. I should have looked into the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS in `html5Mode` uses [html5 history routing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to get rid of the `#` in the url. This works as long as you navigate in the webpage.

The browser requested your `index.html` once (which set up your app and especially `ngRoute`), and clicking `<a href="/home">Home</a>` etc. *does not cause requests* to the server. Instead, ngRoute looks up the route, manipulates the html5 history and shows you what you clicked.

However, you have to tell the browser that performs the `localhost:3000/home` request someone typed into the url bar that he in fact wants `index.html` (not `home/index.html`, which does not exist). This means **you have to configure your server** to support html5 history routing. The [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) documentation has a long post about this.

Here's what you'd add if you use [express](http://expressjs.com/):

```javascript
// this must be the last middleware added to your express app
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html'); // specify the path to your index.html here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The web app I'm making is front end only and is on shared hosting. So I guess I can't change server code. I guess I'll have to go back to using the normal routing.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `/home` directly to the address bar, you're asking the server for a document in the `/home` path, when you actually want the AngularJS application in a document in the root path to load the `/home` route. You need to configure your server to redirect any request other than the root path to the root path, and pass the specified path after a `#`, for example, redirect `/home` to `#/home`.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses ngRoutes to navigate without leaving the page. If your route contains the # sign followed by the route then you are still on the same page. Angular does this so that it can have persistent variables between views. If you redirect to /home instead of #/home you are loading a static path to the /home folder on your server and Angular will reload when the new page loads, all variables will be cleared.

Comment: I tried following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol) to remove the # in the URL.