# Where can I edit the .htaccess file in Firebase Hosting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, firebase, firebase-hosting

I need to edit my htaccess file to remove the hashbang # in the urls of my angular website (step 3 out of 3). I host my website on Firebase and develop in c9. Where can I edit the htaccess file?

Comment: There is no htaccess file for Firebase Hosting. But that also sounds like an XY problem. If you want to rewrite URLs to all point to the same HTML file, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html#section-rewrites

Comment: Will that remove the #! from the url as well?

Comment: Nope. A rewrite doesn't change anything about the URL in the browser. That is typically something you can set in the SPA framework (such as Angular in your case).

Comment: Since this third step (modifying the .htaccess file) is needed, doesn't it mean that it is therefore not possible to use HTML5 mode with Firebase Hosting for Angular websites? Very pity!

Comment: Many developers host their single-page applications on Firebase Hosting. Keep in mind that we have no idea what "step 3" is, nor do I know what you mean by "HTML5 mode". An mcve would go a long way towards being able to help you get your app running.

Comment: The question is coming from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14771091/4262057. Here a solution is given with $locationProvider to enable HTML5 mode and thus remove the # in the urls. However, when applied, it cannot handle direct urls (e.g. I can go to website.com but not website.com/custom). To overcome this, the users say that the .htaccess files needs to be modified, typically done at your hosting provider. That is why I was wondering how this was done in Firebase. But perhaps there are better ways to remove the # with Firebase?

Comment: Just to add, .htaccess file is provided in the repo for Apache servers

Comment: Here is another useful resource: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanna call out that solution is mentioned in one of the comments.

Firebase allows specifying rewrite config. Just using [this example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html#section-rewrites) straight away is sufficient to get pretty URLs for AngularJS app (provided you've enabled HTML5 mode).