# Why does setting the URL hash through AngularJS's $location.hash add an extra "#/" before the hash?

Tags: angularjs, url, routes, hashbang

After adding the statement `$location.hash('tab1');`, I expected the URL to change to '/#tab1' but it becomes '/#/#tab1'.

What is causing the extra '#/' to appear and how can I avoid it?

UPDATE:
To clarify, I do not want to remove the hash from the fragment URL but the empty path. Per my syntax `$location.hash('tab1');`, I expected the browser URL to become '/#tab1' but it became '/#/#tab1'.

Comment: if you use the $locationProvider.html5Mode(true), in one of your configs then you will not have the initial # but since you want it... why not just navigate without the hash... /tab1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the hashtag from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra '#/' is caused by $locationProvider configuration. It can be removed by

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

See [Removing the hashtag from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14771362)

Comment: Enabling the html5Mode would turn the URL to '/tab1' instead of '/#tab1", right?

Comment: It will transform /#/tab1 to /tab1

Comment: Per my question, I want /#/#tab1 to become /#tab1 not /tab1. Your answer and the question you linked missed this difference.

Comment: First you should set up HTML5 mode to avoid duplication of the hash tag. Then you can use `$location.hash('tab1')` to set the hash to #tab1.

Comment: In your case by applying `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` you'll get */#tab1* instead of */#/#tab1*. I guess it is exactly what you liked to get. Isn't it? You can simply check it in your app.