# Remove # from angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have used the way suggested in [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol) and i have done the changes as below :

In index.html page

```
<head>
<base href="/">
</head>
```

In app.route.js

```
angular.config(configure);
  configure.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
  function configure($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
     .state('home', {
       url: '/',
       views: {
         'contentView': {
           templateUrl: 'app/modules/home/home.html',
           controller: 'HomeController as vm'
         }
       },
     })

 .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
          'contentView': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController as vm'
          }
        },
        data: { login: true }
      })
```

In Web.config File, I have created a rule like below

```
<rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
```

Without doing the above changes, my url was like - http://localhost/projectname/#/
but after above implementation the site is not running. Can anyone suggest where i am doing wrong

Comment: Could you try moving the  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); line below your states? So at the end of the file?

Comment: tried..but no luck..:(

Answer (score 0):

Few things missing in your URL rewriting:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="My App Route" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(your APi path)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```