# angular Js url navigation after getting rid of #

Tags: angularjs, url, url-routing, radix

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol#comment32839975_14771362) I was able to fix the # problem in my URL. It works fine without the URL.

In index.html

```
  <base href="/app-name/">
```

My URL :

```
http://localhost:7001/app-name
```

Before applying base URL I had

```
http://localhost:7001/app-name/#/home
```

1) When I type this in browser how does the URL change to   `http://localhost:7001/app-name/home`?

I was able to change and navigate to diff levels of application when using #. But, after applying base in index.html I am unable to perform this and the browser throws a 404. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Here is my navigation page

```
<div class='navbar-header'>
    <a class='navbar-brand' href="home"><img alt='img' src="appName/images/logo.PNG" type="image/png" height="30"></a>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home"><b>App - Name</b></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="home"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="logs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> YYYYYYYYY </a></li>
        <li><a href="info"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> XXXXXXXX</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Router looks like this.

```
  'use strict';

appName.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'appName/models/scheduler/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/logs', {
        templateUrl : 'appName/models/logs/logs.html',
        controller  : 'logsController'
    })

    .when('/info', {
        templateUrl : 'appName/models/quick_info/info.html',
        controller  : 'yyyyController'
    })

    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});

 //   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        });
```

Thanks for taking time to look into this.

Comment: My guess is you are getting the 404, because the server doesn't know it should return the angular app for a particular address.

Comment: @MattWay Correct.  Now I should find a way to configure this in weblogic server. Trying this article now (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)...But i'm not using ui-router. Using angular-route

Comment: I usually have a catch all in my server (`*` for node.js) that returns the app for any url.

Comment: My server side application is written in spring REST..How do I configure this for an app deployed in weblogic?

Comment: No luck. I have added <wls:session-descriptor>
  <wls:url-rewriting-enabled>true</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
 </wls:session-descriptor> to my weblogic.xml...did not work still throwing 404.