# How can i remove hashtag(#) in my localhost URL path(AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to remove the # symbol from angular.js urls?
for example :

my localhost path is :http://localhost/domain/html/beta/#/home

how can i remove #(Hashtag).

Comment: check this link https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the hashtag from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: @SatejS is it possible in localhost ! removing # tag ??? i have no idea about duplicate !

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove hashbang (#) from your url, your need to switch to html5mode.

```
angular.module('scotchy', [])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller : mainController
        })


    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And in your head tag:

```
<base href="/">
```

Read more about it here: [remove hastag from url.](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)