# AngularJS unable to refresh page after removing # from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router, location-provider

I've an angularJS application where I've a requirement to remove the `#` from the url.
So, I've used some script and made it work.

**Script**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: true,
     requireBase: false
});
```

But now, when I'm refreshing the page by clicking `f5`, I'm unable to get the page content.
So, I've followed some steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27011093/2027813) and made some web.config changes, but unable to get it.

I'm unable to login after putting the `rewrite` rule in web.config
I'm unable to make a `ajax call` to make loginrequest.

How do I do this?

Comment: remove # from anchors and from routes definition too

Comment: there is no # in both anchor tags and also route definitions

Comment: Did you get it fix? i am facing the same issue.

Comment: You need to configure the server to serve the index.html on any url