# Angular removing hash from Urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Long story short**:

Our website page got moved from a single page style to wordpress style by our designer, which has sections scrolling to which change hash in the URL. Since our earlier page was written in angularJS, we ported the whole angular code to one of the section, rest of the sections just praise our website.

Works fine!

But the issue occurs when a user tries to open the section directly from other page using hash. Eg.
http://www.example.com/#/section4

The angular removes this  has from the url and renders the page without scrolled to the mentioned section. This I verified, by removing angular and trying to open static html page.

Any ideas why this might be happening.
If any confusion in my question, please comment. I am pretty confused myself at the moment :)

**Edit 1:**

The usual flow of pages is the page scrolls to the section which has name same as hashtag.
I want to have this functionality in my angular application.
Don't want to remove the hashtag.

Comment: You have `<section id="/section4">`? With a slash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the hashtag from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: its something like <section name="section4"></section>

Comment: @KhalidHussain Its not about using  html5 or hashtag routing. Its about default hashtag functionality(scrolling to section) to work with angular.

Comment: Currently are you using angular routing? From your `URL`, I assume that you are using angular routing. Can you add your routing code?

Comment: You told that your website got moved from single page style to word-press style. But your `URL` (`http://www.example.com/#/section4`) indicates that still you are using angular routing. Generally, you will find `/#/` in `URL` if it uses Angularjs. [For word-press, Please have a look at this demo](http://wataruoguchi.com/LAB/infiniteScroll/)

Comment: Sorry my bad. Not using routing in this page. Routing is used once you login and move in the portal.
And hash urls are found in websites which have scrolls. Once you start scrolling, the hash in the url changes according to the section you are in

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes), if you enable `html5mode` you should be able to use normal hash navigation.

Comment: the url became: www.example.com/signup#home

Answer (score 0):

Hi There Just Include this code into your Config File..

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: true,
     requireBase: false
  });
```

Comment: It made the url look like : www.example.com/signup#home