# %2F is replacing the forward slash when $locationProvider.html5Mode is true

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to beautify an angular site. The trailing hashtag is a pain and it is conflicting with how Spiders crawl the site. So basically `domain.com/about` is shown `domain.com/#/about`, but when spiders hit the non-hashtag version they get a 404. Long story short, I want the hashtag gone lol

I followed this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol) and it got me pretty far by using the code below.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
});
```

I was able to get rid of the hashtag. But only on the home page. Any other page got even weirder.

Now the `domain.com/#/about` actually looks like `domain.com/#%2Fabout`.

Can anyone tell me how can simply get rid of the hashtag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have an anchor tag like this:

```
<a ng-href="#/about">About</a>
```

Replace `#/` with `/`. So modified anchor tag should look like this:

```
<a ng-href="/about">About</a>
```

Hope this solve your problem. If it does not solve your problem, please add detail code. Without detail information, it is difficult to answer question.