# Angular JS send common headers with http post redirect

Tags: angularjs, redirect, express, header, http-post

I am working with angular js and node express using jwt as authentication mechanism. I used http post in angular as post my username and password and it successfully generate the jwt token. but it is not possible to redirect any other page. How can I set that token as header in other pages through angular JS.

My angular controller is,

```
  var app = angular.module('authenticate', []);

  app.controller('AuthenticateCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.login = function() {
          option={'name':$scope.name,'password':$scope.password}
          $http({
          method : "POST",
          url : "/api/authenticate",
          data:option
          }).then(function mySucces(response) {
          $scope.message = response.data;
          //$scope.getData(response.data);
          $http.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = response.data;
          window.location.href = '/api/home';
          alert("You are logged in.!");
          }, function myError(response) {
          $scope.message = response.statusText;
          //console.log(response.data);
          console.log(response.statusText);
          var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'Login failed!',
              template: 'Please check your credentials!'
          });
          });
          }

  });
```

**HTML** script is,

```
  <body ng-controller="AuthenticateCtrl">
  <div class="container">
  <h2>.</h2>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" placeholder="Name" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" /></p>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required="" class="form-control" /></p>
    <button ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
    <hr />
    {{ message }}
</div>
  </body>
```

and the POST request handling node js part is,

```
apps.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(dirname+'/public/home.html');
    });
```

But the redirected home page shows

```
{"success":false,"message":"No token provided."}
```

message. Which is my authentication failure message.
Anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [an interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to set the `x-access-token` and you should use [routing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) to navigate. You should not use `window.location.href` to navigate in an Angular SPA.

A sample interceptor looks like this:

```
app.factory('sampleInterceptor', ['$location', function ($location) {
    var sampleInterceptorFactory = {};
    var _request = function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers['x-access-token'] = authData;
        return config;
    }
    sampleInterceptorFactory.request = _request;
    return sampleInterceptorFactory;
}]);
```

A sample router looks like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      }).
      when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: How interceptor and routing working in angular. would you please suggest an example.?

Comment: Yes, I've edit my answer to include examples for both.

Comment: When I redirect using router there is a # before the url.

Comment: You can use the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/q/14771091/385280 to remove the #.