# How to remove '#' in $location.path?

Tags: angularjs, express

I have a login page and what I wanted to get is redirect me to `localhost:2000/home` when the credentials are correct.

However, when I try to redirect myself to `/home` as I log in, it redirect instead to: `localhost:2000/#/home`

NOTE: I have already tried to set `locationProvider.html5Mode` to `true`.

Here's what I've done so far:

Here's my code for my controller:

```
$scope.submitLoginForm = function(isValid) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        if (isValid) {
            //placeholder

            $scope.err = '';
            alert('Your form has been processed!');
            var data = {
              'email': $scope.email,
              'password': $scope.password
            }

            loginService.loginCredentials(data);
```

And here's my code to the login service:

```
function loginCredentials(data, callback) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    $http.post("http://" + constants.local_api_host + ':'+ constants.local_api_port + '/' + constants.user_prefix + '/login', $.param(data))
    .then(function(response){

      if (response.data.error){
        console.log(response.data.message);
        var return_info = {
          error: response.data.error,
          message: response.data.message
        }
        return return_info
      }
      console.log("Success");
      $location.path('home');
    })
```

Here's my route in angular:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: mainController
      })
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: mainController
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
  });
]);
```

I also have configured my `index.html` and `home.html` to have `base href='/'`.
And it's still not working.

As for my code in express, here's the code I configured for the routes:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/'+ 'index.html');
});

app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/partials/'+ 'home.html');
});
```

What do I do to resolve this? Thank you. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: I tried that out, but it didn't work. I already set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in my `$routeprovider` code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set html5mode to true to remove '#'.

```
 angular.module('myApp', []).
   config(['$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

You need to add

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And also use $state.go() instead of $location.path();

```
$state.go('home');
```

Comment: please use $state.go() instead of $location.path().

Comment: Have you added a base tag below your `<html>`tag of your index.html file: `<base href="/">`