# Changing the url to /home instead /#/home in angularJS App

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app that I want to change the url for each page. The urls are showing up as ".com/#/home" instead of ".com/home". Any Ideas?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.home', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('HomeCtrl', [function() {

}]);
```

Comment: Why do you care what the URL is?

Comment: This question has been asked before. You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing mode determines what the URL of your site will look like.
The default behavior of the $location service is to route using the **hashbang mode**.

A hashbang URL looks like:

xyz.com/#/inbox/all

The other routing mode that AngularJS supports is **html5Mode**. This mode makes your URLs look like regular URLs

HTML5 mode would look like:

xyz.com/inbox/all

You can explicitly configure **hashbang** mode, it needs to be configured in the config function on an app module.

For Example.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}]);
```

To explicitly configure **html5Mode** mode.

For Example.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Hashbang mode is the default mode that AngularJS uses if it’s not told otherwise.