# Angular.js Active nav elements

Tags: angularjs

I trying change the colour of the links getting the path, it is working but not the way I want.

what is happening now is this:

I am in `http://localhost:8000/projects.html` right fine?

if I click in the next link like home goes to: `http://localhost:8000/projects.html#/index.html`

i want this link goes to : `http://localhost:8000/index.html` instead of `http://localhost:8000/projects.html#/index.html`

understanding what I saying? how can I fix this? thank you.

**app.js**

```
App.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.items = [
      {path: '/index.html', title: 'Home'},
      {path: '/projects.html', title: 'Projects'},
      {path: '/contributions.html', title: 'Contributions'},
    ];
    $scope.isActive = function(item) {
      if (item.path == $location.path()) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };
  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl1', [function() {
  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {
  }]);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{active: isActive(item)}">
          <a href="#{{item.path}}">{{item.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are wanting to provide page level navigation within the application, you may want to take a look at how ngRoute and ui-router works

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to enable html5 mode(SPA app)? [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Or redirect without SPA? If last, use html5mode = true and target="_blank"

Comment: thanks, so how will be that in my code? can you help me?

Comment: App.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){ $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); }])