# want to remove # from my angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, hashbang, ui-sref, location-provider

want to remove # from my angularjs application
i have tried $locationProvider, but there is no luck

**here is my Config :**

```
var TechdefeatApp = angular.module('TechdefeatApp',['ui.router']);
TechdefeatApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")

    $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "app/components/home/homeView.html",
        controller:"homeController"
    })
    .state('post', {
        url: "/post/:seo_url",
        templateUrl: "app/components/post/postView.html",
        controller:"postController"
    })
}]);
```

**i am calling a URL using ui-sref:**

```
<a ui-sref="post({seo_url:post.seo_url})" title="{{post.title}}">{{post.title}}</a>
```

The URL in browser appear like this :

```
URL : http://jaancari.com/latest/#/post/un-ambassador-nikki-haley
URL : http://jaancari.com/latest/#/post/december-3-1984-bhopal-worst-industrial-accident-in-history
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called hashbang. To remove it you have to enable html5-mode in your angular config like this:

```
    var TechdefeatApp = angular.module('TechdefeatApp',['ui.router']);
    TechdefeatApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider ){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")

        $stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "app/components/home/homeView.html",
            controller:"homeController"
        })
        .state('post', {
            url: "/post/:seo_url",
            templateUrl: "app/components/post/postView.html",
            controller:"postController"
        })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

You can read more about hashbang and html-mode here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: You mean i have to user either $stateProvider or $locationProvider .?

Comment: i edit my answer with your code... You only have to inject $locationProvider and set html5 mode to true... this should work. Adding base-href and tell your server to route every request to index.html is also a good idea - see answer from @Bangsi

Comment: i have Tried the same Long Back by Referring [Link ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: so what is your result with the code above? Have an error? Nothing happens and hashbang is still there?

Comment: No Error is Coming, Nothing Happening

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following

**$locationProvider and html5Mode**

Do this when defining your Angular application and configuring your routes.

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

**Set relative links**

Set a `<base>` in the `<head>` of your document.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```

**Change .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ./index.html [L]
```

Comment: i have tried $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); but there is no luck.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I'd hope you tried the other methods too

Comment: Yes i have Tried you Procedure as well still No Luck.