# Random # getting set in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

### Issue

---

I am trying to use the UI-Router in my AngularJS application and I'm seeing a random `#` inside the URL which is messing everything up.

So I have my **index.html** which is the single page inside the application which holds my UI-View.

```
<body>
    <div id="view" ui-view></div>
</body>
```

On load of the **index.html** i want to load the partial **login.html** which it does and the URL looks fine:

```
http://localhost:55462/
```

But when I click the button I call:

```
$location.path('/forgotpasswordcode');
```

Which then i have set in my Routing:

```
.state('forgotpassword', {
    url: '/forgotpassword',
    templateUrl: 'partials/forgotpassword.html',
    controller: 'forgotPasswordController'
})
```

But the URL now looks like this:

```
http://localhost:55462/#/forgotpassword
```

I was wondering why there has been a `#` added in the URL?

Comment: because angular... look up `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

Comment: In addition to what @corn3lius said - this shouldn't be "messing everything up".

Comment: in addition to the above `$location.path('/forgotpasswordcode');` would not go to the state you posted since the urls don't match

Comment: discussion and answers on the topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Comment: @corn3lius Does this work when using UI-Router rather than ngRoute?

Comment: @danchik I changed and added but the url looks like this now `http://localhost:55462/#forgotpassword`

Comment: you need to add `<base href="/" />` to the html also look here for other fixes. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/372 You also need to make sure your server will only respond with your main index page and not try to load `/otherpage.html` from the backend.