# Unable to remove # in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

The application is making use of the following:

1. AngularJS (v1.6.4)
2. webpack
3. ui-router

One requires the path to be independent of the ***#*** in the url.

For this I have added the following in the code:

In **app.js**

```
 /* in the config section */
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

In **index.html**

```
 <!-- under the head section -->
 <base href="/">
```

When fired in the below format from address

```
'http://localhost/pathName'
```

it gives the following error:

> **Cannot GET /pathName**

But the same works well when accessed through hyperlinks.
Also, on accessing *'http://localhost/#/pathName'*, the browser modifies the same to *'http://localhost/pathName'*.

Is there a way by which the url can be accessed through GET request, by configuring from webpack (or some other way)?

**EDIT 1:**

Routing Code:

```
.config(($stateProvider) => {
    $stateProvider
        .state('pathName', {
            url: '/pathName',
            template: '<pathNameTemplate />'
        });
})
```

Comment: Can you paste your route code?

Comment: @Avihaym, I don't think, it is required, but still I have added.

Comment: The issue is on your server. You must configure your server to always return your base view

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe, can u explain how can I do it; the application is basically a frontend itself with no server-side technologies like NodeJS, etc.

Comment: How could I help you without knowing your server? Your error happens while the javascript code has not been loaded to the browser yet. There is nothing you can do with your JS code to handle that

Comment: try use this chorme extension to load your page. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol#14771362

Comment: Yes you need to configure your server to return your /index.html or whatever HTML page hosts your app, when the user requests `http://localhost/pathName`.  You will need to do that for every URL of your app. What server are you hosting this on?

Answer (score 1):

No html5:

1. user types `www.site.com/#/section` in browser
2. request is sent for `www.site.com` (#... is ignored)
3. server return index.html
4. angular launches and see that there is # -- loads specific view

Html5:

1. user types `www.site.com/section` in browser
2. request is sent for `www.site.com/section`
3. server return index.html
4. angular launches and see that there is / -- loads specific view 
   So server MUST return index.html for all your paths -  i.e. this means that you can not make it work from file system (file://.../). You need server and configure it adding redirects

P.S. you do not need this line

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sample to remove **#** from url using

- **AngularJs** *v1.5.7*
- **ui-router** *v0.4.2*
- **web.config**

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]);
```

**app.config**

```
var config = function (locationProvider) {
    locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
config.$inject = ["$locationProvider"];
app.config(config);
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
   <base href="/" />
</head
```

> If you don't use **IIS Service**, and use **Apache service** such as xamp or etc... for your localhost change it to `<base href="/sample/" />`

**web.config**

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

> **Note**: you have to add this config because without it, when # removed after refresh [F5] you lose the state.
>
> Remember In **Apache (PHP)** configs are different, and users have to add the settings in the **.htaccess** file.