# remove # symbol from URL in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am beginner in AngularJS and i am trying to remove `#` symbol from URL and i am using `Visual Studio code` IDE ,I did below steps for remove `#` from URL and when i launch Application with `HTTP Live server` its working and `#` removed from URL but when i reload page i am getting 404 can some one suggest me please

### app.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider,$locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/employeeList');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })
       .state('employeeList', {
            url: '/employeeList',
            templateUrl: 'templates/list_of_employees.html',
            controller: 'EmployeeController'
        })
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('')

});
```

### index.html

```
<head>
  <base href='/'>
</head>
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Comment: Ahmed Ghoniem i did same i n my above code please che ck

Comment: remove .hashPrefix('')

Just keep $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: That's not problem even when remove it's not working

Comment: I am using vs code I think we have to set something in web.config file but in vs code there is no web.config file

Comment: its not related to vs code. VS code is just a code editor like notepad. 
web.config is for .net projects

Comment: I am front end developer that's why give me clarity

Comment: So server side have to remove # need not front end right?

Answer (score 0):

Using this $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html).

Assuming you are using Apache and your index file is index.php or index.html , try adding the following to your .htaccess file to create a rewrite rule.

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
      RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php/#/$1 
   </IfModule>
```

Comment: Where should I use this code?

Comment: you need to create a .htaccess file in your project folder

Comment: How can I create ?

Comment: can we create this in vsCode?

Comment: create a new file with file named .htaccess

Comment: ok let me try and tell result

Comment: can you connect to my system?

Comment: please show me the way once