# Links need to refer to "#/route"

Tags: angularjs

When I go to the route `localhost/project_root/items` I get a page not exists error. However, `localhost/project_root/#/items` is working.

Can I in some way use regular links, `<a href="items">` instead of doing `<a href="/#/items">`?

Here's my routing

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/items', {
            templateUrl: 'js/modules/items/partials/items.html'
        }).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS routing without '#'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without)

Comment: read $routeProvider docs

Comment: There is no proper solution there. The accepted answer is not compatible with `IE10`

Comment: The solution in that answer is the only viable solution. As far as I know, it should work fine for IE10. If it's not, make sure your IE is not stuck in compatibility mode or something. There's a meta-tag that can force IE to not use compatibility mode.

Comment: I don't how many times I've had a client complain "It's not working" only to go to them and look at their IE and see that its running in that god awful compatibility mode.  What makes it worse is that they tend to mistakenly turn it on all the time because the button is right next to IE's reload button, then on top of that the little broken document icon only changes color - so which color is on and which is off?