# Google Analtyics adds hashtag to browser url on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-analytics

When adding google analytics to our site, everywhere we are using the hashtag for example dropDown (bootstrap.js, jquery) of a item, the hastag gets added to the url in the browser. Is there anyway to remove this? I am using angulartics with angularjs.

For example, href="#collapseTwoCheckout" results in http://yourdomain.org/#/collapseTwoCheckout

When removing GA script, this goes away. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Google Analytics that adds the hashtag to your url, it's a function in the angular ng-route module. I'm not sure why it only occurs when you have analytics loaded, but you can get rid of the hashtag by removing the ng-route module from your angular installation or set the html5mode to "true" in the configuration of your angular application.

Maybe you should read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14320468/2274628

Comment: It does not help. I have added this and all that it does is takes away the first hash. http://yourdomain.org/collapseTwoCheckout#collapseTwoCheckout

Comment: How do you get that URL?
Are you at yourdomain.org/collapseTwoCheckout ?
And then you click at the href="#collapseTwoCheckout" ?

Comment: No, collapseTwoCheckout is only a name of the section in a dropdown. The url should be the same page. We are opening different dropdown menus on the same page.