# Angular dart bookmarking views

Tags: dart, angular-dart

It is my experience that Angular Dart is agnostic to your backend server implementation. it doesn't care if your server is in java, ruby or whatever. Angular dart has the concept of views and has a module that deals with routing between them. these routes also modify the address bar of the browser when it changes views.

I have come across this issue. Though the angular router module will change the address bar, because said route doesn't actually exist as far as the backend server is concerned, and as such will always issue a 404 response.

If such is the case, then I find the ability to route to different pages via angular to be pointless. Might as well I code in a more traditional server oriented fashion to transition between pages, than to sue angular.

Is it that there is something that is missing? Is there a way you can can get your server to resolve to the correct angular page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `usePushState: false` then only the (client) local part of the URL is changed.
see https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_06/web/main.dart#L27
This part after the hash is never sent to the server.
This might cause some additional work for SEO.

```
http://example.com/index.html#someRoutePath/anotherRoutePath
```

or you can configure your server in a way that each request is handled independent of the path in the request and use the route package server side too.

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909743/217408

Comment: Wow, this solution just works out of the box without having to change anything in my backend server. It's one job is just server the files.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your backend server to point all routes to the same file (using some kind of wildcard route which all decent servers should support). So `app/some/page` and `app/another/page` would both be served `app.html`. Then on your app startup you could have Angular parse the URL of the page, and manually route to that page.

I have used this approach with a Polymer app (with the Route library) and it works great. It should work similarly for Angular.