# Dart Polymer Routing

Tags: angularjs, routes, dart, polymer, angular-dart

I have a single page app using Dart and Polymer. I'm trying to add a route to another page with [route_hierarchical](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route_hierarchical)

What I've tried so far was configuring the router like this:

```
router = new Router()
router.root
  ..addRoute(name: 'games', path: '/games')
  ..addRoute(name: 'login', path: '/login')
  ..addRoute(name: 'home', defaultRoute: true, path: '/');
router.listen();
```

I've found that I can use

```
new Router(useFragment: ...);
```

to enable the hashbangs in the URLs or not. The problem is that when I don't use hashbangs, I can't access a page using the URL directly. (meaning the app routes me when I click on buttons and such). Is there a way of having sharable URLS with no hashbangs? I've seen AngularJs using something like

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

to remove the hashbangs and still have sharable URLs... I don't know if I really should bother having URLs without hashbangs though. I've read having them is going to give me trouble with SEO, is that right?

I'm only using Polymer and route_hierarchical right now, and didn't want to go for angular.dart just for  routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a router on the server side too when you want to use URLs without fragments.

see also

- [httpd.conf and HTML5 pushstate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034082)
- [Angular dart bookmarking views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329525)
- [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967)

Comment: and do what with it? Return html pages? I thought it was the whole point of SPA.

Comment: When routing on the client modifies the URL you need a counterpart on the server so the generated URLs return the expected ressources.
There are already similar questions with answers with good explanations. I try to find one and add a link ...

Comment: I found a few pages (see my updated answer). The explanation there is not too extensive but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: so if I'm not mistaken, your links give solutions with webservers like Apache/Nginx. So to my understanding, I would have to add a rewrite rule to my webserver, so it doesn't serve manage links with no extensions (and let the client manage it?)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment. The route package generates URLs which don't actually exist. You need a way to make the server interpret them correctly. You can use rewrite rules for web servers or use the a routing package if for example a Dart server app serves ressourses or a combination (web server for ststic ressources, server app for dynamic ressourses) or don't use pushState but URL fragments instead.

Comment: My current setup is running the app using pub for developing (no backend involved) and serving html+js compiled files with Nginx. So I guess I could write rewrite rules for nginx, however I won't be able to use the urls while developing, right?

Comment: I don't know nginx but I guess you could create rewrite rules that forward to `pub serve` during dev.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68515/discussion-between-pacane-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on my computer anymore. We can chat tomorrow.