# How to use route

Tags: routes, dart

I'm trying to use route package on my client in dart.
Here the code :

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:route/url_pattern.dart';
import 'package:route/client.dart';

final UrlPattern homeUrl = new UrlPattern(r'/');
final UrlPattern contactUrl = new UrlPattern(r'/contact');

void main() {
    new Router(useFragment: true)
        ..addHandler(homeUrl, showHome)
        ..addHandler(contactUrl, showContact)
        ..listen();
}

void showHome(String path) {
    window.alert("Home");
}

void showContact(String path) {
    window.alert("Contact");
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080`, the popup "Home" appears, fine.
But when I go to `http://localhost:8080/contact` I've got a

```
404 Not Found
Could not find asset web/contact in package DartApplication.
```

If I go to `http://localhost:8080/#/contact`, nothing happens.

Can you help me guys? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to implement matching server side routing or disable the use of onPushState. See also [Dart Polymer Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861634/dart-polymer-routing/27861712)