# How do I get rid of the /#/ when using ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular and I am currently doing my routes with ui.router and was curious about something. I notice when I go to my site either on localhost or online, my URL includes /#/ at the end of it. Home looks like domain.com/#/ and other pages follow suite ( domain.com/#/about ) How do I make it appear without the hash?

Here is an example of my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('dashboardApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(
    ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        //Dashboard states and nested views ========================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: './templates/main/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
        })

        //Subject states and nested views ==========================
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: './templates/main/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutCtrl'
        });
    }]);
```

And here is how I am calling it in my DOM

```
<div class="main-nav">
    <a ui-sref="home"><img src="randomimage.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="main-nav">
    <a ui-sref="about">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: set it : $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hasbang is there for compatibility reasons with the older browsers.
Here is a thread for the same question:

[AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

And here is a blog post explaining how to get rid of the hashbang safely with fallback for older browsers:

http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Essentially, you can use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to eliminate the hashbang for the "HTML5 ready" browsers and Angular will fall back automatically to the hashbang version for the older browsers.

Comment: That looks like it should help. Should it matter that I am using ng-include to bring in my navigation items from a separate file on my index.html?

Comment: No, it shouldn't make a difference.