# AngularJS $routeProvider can't load directly to partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, angularjs-routing

At the minute I'm currently using the $routeProvider to dynamically load sections of the page like so:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/our-business', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/our-business.html',
        controller: 'businessController',
        css: 'css/_business.css'
    })
    .when('/solutions', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/solutions.html',
        controller: 'solutionsController'
    });
```

Currently, if I go directly to the index (localhost) and then select 'Our Business' from the navigation menu then Angular handles the location request and the page loads fine, with the URL changing to *localhost/our-business*. If I then reload, or open this URL directly I get a 404 error - presumably because Apache is trying to open our-business.html which doesn't exist. If I open *localhost/#/our-business* then the index is loaded and Angular then handles the request. The issue I've got is that this is designed to be a public facing website, so if a user were to copy and paste the URL or share it via email, they'll get a 404 error.

Is there any way to have Apache rewrite URLs to parse them via the index and AngularJS so that we can keep the non-hash style but still have functional URLs?

Comment: Can you try to use HTML5 mode like $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);. For more details refer [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode).

Comment: I had the same problem. This is how I fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21484874

Answer (score 1):

As said Kailash you can set the locationProvider to html5 mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

when you bootstrap your angular application.

Then you have to tell your Apache server to send the index.html (entry point of you single page app) for any requested url.

The angular router will then handle the proper route

Comment: Thanks Laurent, this looks promising but when I set the following rewrite on the server:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) /synergi/index.html [L]
</IfModule>

All the javascript files are replaced by the index.html code.

Comment: Yes sorry I was not clear: serve your statics as usual, but any url which does not match your static folder should return index.html

Answer (score -1):

Nope. Changing the url without the hash reloads the entire page.

The entire point of this `$routeProvider` is to build single-page app with multiple views.

Basically, having the `#` in the url is the only way to do that. Changes to a url's hash don't result in a page reload, and allow Angular to load the relevant views.